# Lap top will not Boot

Tags: boot

I have downloaded and installed Ubuntu erasing XP in the process. It seemed to install correctly up to the point where I reboot. Machine will not boot. I have just a flashing curser on top left of blank screen. Can you help please?
Kind regards
Eleanor

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more detail? For example, do you see the boot message of the bios, like it is an HP or ... If so can you boot into a live session by using the live cd or usb zou used to install ubuntu? If so may be just the grub boot loader is f...ed up, which you can recover using the information provided by the following link.

[how to restore grub](http://odzangba.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/455/)

Just type the commands into the terminal and you should be fine.

good luck